# R: Shadindg under several normals with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot several normal distributions and shade the area under every curve to the right of x=6 and to the left of the symetrical value...

I've defined two functions to do it easily.

```
mifun <- function(x,mm,ss,alt) {
  y <- alt+dnorm(x, mean = mm, sd = ss)
  return(y)
}

mifun2 <- function(x,mm,ss,alt) {
  y <- alt+dnorm(x, mean = mm, sd = ss)
  y[x<6 & (2*mm-x)<6 ] <- NA
  return(y)
}


ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-5, 11)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun(x,0,2,0), geom = "line") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun2(x,0,2,0), geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun(x,2,2,-0.4), geom = "line") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun2(x,2,2,-0.4), geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun(x,4,2,-0.8), geom = "line") + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun2(x,4,2,-0.8), geom = "area") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun(x,6,2,-1.2), geom = "line") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) mifun2(x,6,2,-1.2), geom = "area") +theme_bw()
```

This is the picture without shading:
[image]

This is the picture with the shading, it doesn't work as expected:
[image]

If I only plot one normal I get this
[image]

As you can see the shade appears above the normals instead of below.

PD:  picture for Mark
[image]
As you can see the first plots are aligned on the right shadow limit, and the latter ones are aligned on the left.

Comment: You might want to consider restructuring your data and code to create stacked line charts

Comment: Or maybe faceted, but I don't know how to do it properly and I first thought it was going to be easier like that.

Comment: `geom_area` fills down (or up) to 0, which is what is causing the odd behavior when you have the location of the "base" of the curve shifted away from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the comments above are right: faceting is going to be the way to go. Unfortunately, `facet_wrap` (and `facet_grid`) don't play well with `stat_function` because there is no good way to pass the faceting variable into `stat_function` (that I can find anyway).

So, instead, you may need to generate your density curves and area to fill first. Note that `geom_area` fills in the gaps between points, so you need to have `mifun2` output `0` instead of `NA` where there is supposed to be no fill:

```
mifun2 <- function(x,mm,ss,alt) {
  y <- alt+dnorm(x, mean = mm, sd = ss)
  y[x<6 & (2*mm-x)<6 ] <- 0
  return(y)
}
```

Then, generate the gridded data.frame you want. Here I am using 4 values for the means (from your question) and 1001 points in the range you want to plot:

```
normCurves <-
  data.frame(x = rep(seq(-5, 11, length.out = 1001)
                     , times = 4)
             , myMean = rep(c(0,2,4,6)
                            , each = 1001))
```

Then, use your two functions to generate plottable columns for the density and area filling:

```
normCurves$density <-
  mifun(normCurves$x, normCurves$myMean, 2, 0)

normCurves$toHighlight <-
  mifun2(normCurves$x, normCurves$myMean, 2, 0)
```

And then plot those directly, using `facet_wrap` to separate out the various means:

```
ggplot(normCurves
       , aes(x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = density)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = toHighlight)) +
  facet_wrap(~myMean, ncol = 1, labeller = label_both)
```

gives:

[image]

This approach also lends itself to plotting everything on top of each other with different colors:

```
ggplot(normCurves
       , aes(x
             , col = factor(myMean)
             , fill = factor(myMean)
             , group = myMean)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = density)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = toHighlight)
            , alpha = 0.2
            , col = NA
            , position = "identity")
```

gives

[image]

If you want it to highlight things that are more extreme than 6 in the other direction (WHY??), you just need to change your `mifun2` definition:

```
mifun2 <- function(x,mm,ss,alt) {
  y <- alt+dnorm(x, mean = mm, sd = ss)

  # Make changes for small means
  y[mm <= 6 & x<6 & (2*mm-x)<6 ] <- 0  

  # Make changes for large means
  y[mm > 6 & x>6 & (2*mm-x)>6 ] <- 0  

  return(y)
}
```

Then, add the addtional means:

```
normCurves <-
  data.frame(x = rep(seq(-6, 18, length.out = 1001)
                     , times = 7)
             , myMean = rep(seq(0, 12, 2)
                            , each = 1001))
```

Now, if you re-run the same plotting code as above, you get:

[image]

You now also mention you want to animate, which is relatively straightforward:

```
toAnimate <-
  ggplot(normCurves
         , aes(x
               , group = myMean
               , frame = myMean)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = density)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = toHighlight)
            , position = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Mean = ")

gganimate::gg_animate(toAnimate)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more normals, shifted more to the left, and reversing the blackening process?
I mean the 5th normal will be shaded like the 3rd one but slightly shifted to the left. The 6th one will be shaded like the 2nd. And the 7th like the 1st but shifted to the left.
I want to use this plot to show how different values of the parameter that defines the normal produce different p-values for a given x. And you could use it to define an interval non-rejectable...

Comment: You can add any means you want, just set the `times` argument for the `x` in the data to the number of means you have, then add the means to the vector of means. What do you mean by "reversing the blackening process"?

Comment: I've added a picture showing you what I mean. Or an approach with your second solution would be nice as well.

Comment: Maybe it's better to create an animation from it.

Comment: I was going to tell we can use y[ifelse(x<k,x<k & (2*mm-x)<k, x>k & (2*mm-x)>k) ] <- 0, but you did it faster :) . ggplot2 is really slow creating this simple graphic. Do you have any advise to improve it? Maybe using other package or a simpler method such as really sliding things instead of recalculating so many points?

Comment: It is slow because it is plotting 1001 points times 7 groups for two aesthetics (14k points total). You can reduce the resolution to get faster plotting, but then will get some artifacts with edges of the shaded regions. You could also try `geom_polygon` as a way to work with reduced resoultion, if waiting a few seconds is really a problem.

Comment: I've also tried to add a line starting when myMean=2 and ending when myMean=10 (in my computer in reallity I'm doing more divisions). I've tried defining a new column "nc$alf" filled with zeroes ones and zeroes again  and adding  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = myMean), colour = "red", size = 1, alpha=nc$alf) but instead of plotting it at every frame it plots all the lines at once at the beginning.  How should I do it?

Comment: You are now well into the range of a separate question. If you want to ask more about `gganimate`, I recommend developing a small MWE that shows your problem, and asking about it directly. Feel free to link from here.